# converting a list with custom class to json file(unity3D)

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

The class that is created

```
[Serializable]
public class Mycustom_gameobject_list
{
    public WayspotAnchorPayload game_object_coordinates;
    public GameObject storing_gameobject;
   
}
[Serializable]
public class Gameobject_lsit : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<Mycustom_gameobject_list> Store_gameobjects_list = new List<Mycustom_gameobject_list>();
}
```

I store my game data into the List, then I try to convert it to json

```
  public static void SaveLocalPayloads(List<Mycustom_gameobject_list> savelist)
    {
 
   
        Debug.Log(savelist.Count);
        convertData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(savelist);
          Debug.Log(convertData);
}
```

Then error [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **not** serialize `GameObject` (or **any** `UnityEngine.Object`) references into JSON to begin with!

The main issue in your case here: Other than the built-in `JsonUtility` the `Newtonsoft Json.NET` you are using **does** serialize properties as well!

Unity built-in types have a lot of **properties** such as [`GameObject.transform`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject-transform.html) which returns a [`Transform`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.html) which itself again has a property [`Component.gameObject`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component-gameObject.html)

=> infinite serialization loop.

What exactly is your goal with the serialized `storing_gameobject`? There is no way Unity can properly restore this when deserializing the JSON anyway.

---

So you should exclude the `GameObject` from the    serialization using the attribute [`[JsonIgnore]`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PropertyJsonIgnore.htm) like

```
[JsonIgnore]
public GameObject storing_gameobject;
```

then **assuming that your list doesn't change its order and size afterwards** you could simply apply the data back after loading like e.g.

```
public static void LoadLocalPayloads(List<Mycustom_gameobject_list> savelist)
{
    var tempList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Mycustom_gameobject_list>(convertData);

    for(var i = 0; i < tempList.Count; i++)
    {
        savelist[i].game_object_coordinates = tempList[i].game_object_coordinates;


        // and probably apply it to according object like e.g.
        savelist[i].storing_gameobject.transform.position = savelist[i].game_object_coordinates.position;
        // etc
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm using the API from ARDK, and the JSON only save the coordinate of that spawn object. When I save with multiple coordinates with different game objects, it all turns into the same game object. And this is the reason I'm trying to save the coordinates and that game object into the same list. If I cant store the game objects into a JSON file, any other method that can achieve the same goal?